# migration from magento 1.9.0.1 to magento 2.0.7

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, php, migration

I have to migrate from magento 1.9.0.1 to magento 2.0.7 with the help of magento **data-migration-tool** provided by magento, but i am stuck in that process.
I am facing following issue while migrating magento database.

```
[PDOException]                                                                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10-Migration_Cell Phones' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'
```

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the attribute sets named `Default` in `eav_attribute_set` table, first.

Then migrate with the `--r` **reset ** option